# Should I write "what do the data show" or "what does the data show"?

Tags: technical-writing, grammar

I wonder what the proper way of writing this question is:

- What do the data show?
- What does the data show?

Comment: Greetings, and welcome to Writers! Your question is currently off-topic, because it is about a specific piece of writing or problem. If you can edit it to help everyone (eg, 'what do you do in this circumstance'), it will be on topic.

Comment: Please note that [grammar is also off-topic here](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/301/should-we-allow-grammar-proofreading-questions), in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the data show?

I believe `data` is a collective noun (though I am not 100% sure on that). Collective nouns are plural only when the context is speaking of their individual parts, or members. Otherwise they are singular. Therefore, you would use `does`, which is the singular form of the verb `do`.

Now if you were to say:

> What do the data **records** show?

Things would be different, because you are referring to the members of the data (records).